# Cant send Ajax to localhost in Apache Cordova. Get ajax error status 0

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova-3

White-list already installed. 
CORS on server enabled.
use in config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="*" />
</platform>
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({        
    url : "http://127.0.0.1",
    type : "POST",
    data : {},
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success : formSuccessAuth,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert(`${xhr.status} ${status} ${error}`);
           }

});
```

meta in index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

After sending req I get the message: `0 error`

Comment: You can't do POST with jsonp requests. They are script requests not XMLHttpRequests. Enable CORS and do regular json instead.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thank you, did not know c:

Comment: CORS already enabled on server and I try to use simple json. And.. now I have ajax satus 0